# Determining if a set is in the subspace of a continuous function

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A={\rm span}\{\cos^2x,\sin^2x\}$ be a subspace of the set of functions $C[0,\pi]$, for each of the following functions in $C[0,\pi]$, determine whether or not it is in $A$.

1. $f(x)=1$
2. $g(x)=3+\cos 2x$
3. $h(x)=x^2$

I'm just confused regarding the path to take, Am I supposed to write those as a linear combination of $A$? Or there is a different solution to this?
I would appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if $\{f(x), \cos^2x,\sin^2x\}$ is linearly dependent or not, same for $g$ and $h$. The first one is almost trivial. For the second one, remember that $\cos(2x) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$. For the third one, you can use the Wronksian test: if $$W[f_1,f_2,f_3](x)=\begin{vmatrix} f_1(x) & f_2(x) & f_3(x) \\ f_1'(x) & f_2'(x) & f_3'(x) \\ f_1''(x) & f_2''(x) & f_3''(x)\end{vmatrix}$$ is non zero for some value of $x$, the functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are either supposed to write each $f(x)$ as a linear combination of $\cos^2x$ and $\sin^2x,$ or show that it cannot be done. (Actually, based on the phrasing, you may only be required to *decide* whether or not it can be done, but being able to justify your claims never hurts.)

Comment: Yea the question is asking for a proof too so i should.

Answer (score 0):

3. Suppose if possible $x^2 = \alpha cos^2 x+\beta sin^2 x$ on $[0, \pi]$ for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$ then what happens at the $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$? And, how many roots does $\beta sin^2 x$ have?